# Joining two postcode tables to give detailed view SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

I have two tables that have postcode details, the first is essentially a high level table that has only the first part of a postcode (example PR2, LL4) and so on. The second table is street level postcode table so it contains full postcodes (PR22JY, LL35GN).

I want to do a join so that they join on postcode on the street view postcode. In the past I have used a `CHARINDEX` to return the first part but the street table is in as a single string with no space and I can't match just based on the first 3 characters as some postcodes have 3 and some have 4.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use surrogate keys - don't rely on the actual **postcode** for reference, use a system-given, separate `ID` value.

I would design the tables something like this:

[image]

The `PostcodeDetail` table references the `PostcodeHighlevel` table by means of the `PostCodeID` column (that's common to both tables - it's the primary key in the high-level table, foreign key in the detail table).

Of course: you can easily add more columns to those tables as needed (e.g. name of the city/region - whatever you need).

My point is just this: don't rely on the actual **postcode** for connecting the two tables - use a **surrogate** column to handle this. That way, you don't need to do any `SUBSTRING` or `CHARINDEX` operations just to join the two tables - those operations also kill your JOIN performance....

Comment: wouldnt this require me to update the postcode steet level table with ID's from the High Level table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from postcode pc inner join postcodedetails pcd on pcd.postcode like pc.postcode'%'
```